# How to fix row alignment issue in bootstrap/Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Github repo (https://github.com/teke85/Luxury_living/tree/add-home-page)

In my bootstrap project I successfully managed to retrieve data dynamically from a javascript object. I noticed that the last row is not aligned correctly. how do i fix this or what could have caused the misalignment? **Please note**, The issue wasn't there before I fetched the data dynamically using Javascript.[image]

Comment: Learn how to use the web inspector. Right click on the offending html and click inspect (chrome). In the inspector you can see how the blocks are aligning and what CSS is causing what.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @azeós thank you for your response. Kindly checkout my code here https://github.com/teke85/Luxury_living/tree/add-home-page.

Comment: @Kinglish first thing I did was use my inspector panel and I couldn't find the issue. Could you please have a look at my code here https://github.com/teke85/Luxury_living/tree/add-home-page

Comment: looking at your code won't be that much help for this - with css issues, it's easier to diagnose by viewing a webpage in the browser and inspecting. Also, sending people to a github repository isn't the way to get help here. search this site for 'How to ask'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the newest version, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Content for column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Content for column 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```